# Unity accessing JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, object, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and Gamesparks. I am getting a Gamesparks object return but I am unable to access the data inside using C#.

```
private void OnScriptMessage(ScriptMessage message)
    {
        switch (message.ExtCode)
        {
            case "EndTurnMessage":
                {
                    var data = message.Data;
                    string playerID = data.GetString("playerID");

                    print(message.JSONString);

                    break;
                }
```

`print(message.JSONString);` displays

```
{"@class":".ScriptMessage","data":{"player":{"status":"win","choice":"scissors","newScore":1},"opponent":{"status":"lost","choice":"paper","newScore":0}},"extCode":"roundWonMessage","messageId":"5c74b1a8bcb1b604f0275ed5","notification":true,"playerId":"5c5b5823642c55481643846d","summary":"ScriptMessage"}
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
```

I wish to get `newScore` etc but I am confused with C# JSON

Comment: Which JSON library you are using?

Comment: What do you mean with `etc` do you need only one value or a complete representation of the json as class(es)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is as follows:

```
"@class":".ScriptMessage","data":{"player":{"status":"win","choice":"scissors","newScore":1},"opponent":{"status":"lost","choice":"paper","newScore":0}},"extCode":"roundWonMessage","messageId":"5c74b1a8bcb1b604f0275ed5","notification":true,"playerId":"5c5b5823642c55481643846d","summary":"ScriptMessage"}
```

You need to deserialize it using -> 
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, @class);

But to just get that one value you'd probably just need a good way of parsing your JSON. Under the base JSON root node is data, playerId, extCode, messageId, notification, summary. You need to treat the field "data" as a JSONObject and then both "player" and "opponent" as JSON Objects. Parse the value within it for 
 newScore.

Your data looks like this:[image]

So your code would look something like this (this is to be used as a general guideline):

```
                var data = message.Data;
                string playerID = data.GetString("playerID");
                var _data = data.GetObject("data"); //whatever to get data as JSON or Object
                var _player = _data.GetObject("player"); //whatever to get data as JSON or Object
                var _opponent= _data.GetObject("opponent"); //whatever to get data as JSON or Object
                int _mscorePlayer = _player.GetInteger("newScore"); //Whatever the getter is for JSON Number it could be GetNumber or something comparable.
                int _mscoreOpponent= _opponent.GetInteger("newScore"); //Whatever the getter is for JSON Number it could be GetNumber or something comparable.
                print(message.JSONString);
                print("your playerId:\t" + playerId);
                print("your newScore:\t" + _mscorePlayer);
                print("opponent newScore:\t" + _mscoreOpponent);
                break;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that :-) Just an edit the `var _data = data.GetObject("data");` is not needed because `var data = message.Data;` is already called

Comment: No worries! I've never used Gamesparks before but it looks pretty dope, I gotta check it out.